# Regex pattern match for a given string

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on project which require to extract all the case number from the given string. Can anyone please help me to create a regex to match the pattern for all the case numbers.

Pattern is like: **alphanumeric must followed with / alphanumeric must followed with / alphanumeric**

```
*Housekeeping Services For the period( 1‐03‐2020 to 31‐03‐2020) ‐ HDC ‐5i
SL.NO HSN/SAC
Code UOM
Facility
Approved
HC
Total Billing
Hours
Actual Manpower
HC
Unit Rate Per
Month Taxable Value
1 HK Supervisor 9985 HR 4 832 4.00 18,644.00 7 4,576.00*
Case no.**MH20/00285/VAS**
Case no. **MH20/00294/GVN1**
Case no. **MH20/000026/MUMR**
Case no. **KA20/00346/BN**
Case no. **DL20/0024/DLH39**
Case no. **MH20/003B30/GUR2**
Case no. **GJ20/001A75/GJ**
Case no. **GJ20/001A77/GJ**
Case no. **MH20/002CK89/GVN1**
*3,15,962.69
2 8,436.64
2 8,436.64
3,72,836.00
AMOUNT IN WORDS:‐ Rupees Three Lakhs Seventy Two Thousand Eight Hundred Thirty Six Only*
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this yourself?

Comment: Yes, I tried something like [a-zA-Z0-9/][a-zA-Z0-9/][a-zA-Z0-9] but it is matching all the available sting with in the phrase and I want to extract only case number instead

Comment: I assume that's what your source actually looks like. Please remove any formatting characters you've added

Answer (score 1):

This one should do the Job

```
[\d\w]{4}/[\d\w]+/[\d\w]+
```